# Lowercase data binding value in View

Tags: angularjs

I want following data binding value of `status` to be in lowercase. As it is not applying the `class` if first letter is capital.

How to lowercase data binding value?

```
<div class="col-sm-4" data-ng-repeat="practice in practices">
    <div class="cardHeader {{practice.status}}">{{practice.name}}</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div class="cardHeader {{practice.status | lowercase}}">
    {{practice.name}}
</div>
```

Suggested use `ngClass`